# How can I plot a polygon with n sides inscribed in a circle and show the area?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, geometry

I am doing some work on Archimedes and want to show what the area of a regular *n*-sided polygon is within a circle.  My professor from two years ago was able to show it with an adjustable slider that increased the number of sides of a polygon. I was wondering if it's possible to tack on an equation to display the area of the polygon.

I'm not very good at plotting with *Mathematica* and need help with all of the code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Related: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ApproximatingPiWithInscribedPolygons/

Answer (score 19):

```
Off[Solve::ztest];
var = {R, r, a, p, s};
assume = Join[
   Thread[var > 0],
   {R > r, Element[n, Integers], n > 2}];
eqns = {
   R == s*Csc[Pi/n]/2,
   r == s*Cot[Pi/n]/2,
   a == n*s^2*Cot[Pi/n]/4,
   p == n*s};

sol = Reverse[Assuming[assume,
     Simplify[Solve[
          Join[eqns, assume], #, Reals][[1]] & /@
       Select[
        Subsets[var, {Length[var] - 1}],
        MemberQ[#, a] &]]]] // FullSimplify;

Manipulate[
 If[IntegerQ[m], v = m, v = 5];
 pts = Table[{Cos[2 Pi*k/v], Sin[2 Pi*k/v]},
   {k, 0, v}];
 Column[{
   Graphics[{
     AbsoluteDashing[8],
     Lighter[Gray, 0.4],
     Circle[],
     If[Not[m === Infinity],
      {Circle[{0, 0}, Cos[Pi/v]],
       Blue,
       Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ Take[pts, 2],
       Text["R", {1/2, 1}*pts[[1]], {0, 2}],
       Magenta, Text["\[Alpha]", Plus @@ Take[pts, 2]/7],
       Text["\[Beta]", 6/7*pts[[3]]],
       Darker[Green, .25],
       AbsoluteDashing[4],
       Line[{{0, 0}, Cos[Pi/v]
          {Cos[5 Pi/v], Sin[5 Pi/v]}}],
       Text["r", Cos[Pi/v]/2
         {Cos[1.1*5 Pi/v], Sin[1.1*5 Pi/v]}]}],
     Dashing[{}],
     Black,
     Thick,
     If[m === Infinity,
      {Circle[{0, 0}]},
      Line[pts]]}],
   Grid[
     ReplacePart[arr = Transpose[
        Join[
         {Style[#, Darker[Blue]] & /@
           {"circumradius", 
            "inradius", "area",
            "perimeter", "edge length",
            "central\nangle, \[Alpha]",
            "interior\nangle, \[Beta]",
            "interior\nangle sum"}},
         tab = (TraditionalForm /@ Join[var,
              {If[m === Infinity, 0,
                Row[{2 Pi/n, " rad", ", i.e., ",
                  FunctionExpand[2 Pi/n/Degree] Degree}]]},
              {If[m === Infinity, "\[Pi] rad, i.e., 180\[Degree]",
                Row[{(n - 2) Pi/n, " rad", ", i.e., ",
                  FunctionExpand[(n - 2) Pi/n/Degree] Degree}]]},
              {If[m === Infinity, "Indeterminate", 
                Row[{(n - 2) Pi, " rad", ", i.e., ",
                  FunctionExpand[(n - 2) Pi/Degree] Degree}]]}]) /.

                    If[m === Infinity,
            Map[#[[1]] -> Limit[#[[-1]] /. s -> 2 R Pi/n,
                n -> Infinity] &, sol, {2}],
            sol]]],
      Flatten[Table[{i, j} -> SpanFromLeft,
        {i, If[m === Infinity, 5, 6], 8},
        {j, 3, 5}]]],
     Frame -> All,
     Alignment -> {Center, Center}] /. n -> m},
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{m, "n", "number of edges"},
  Join[{"n"}, Range[3, 20], {Infinity}],
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Quite well-polished :)

Comment: @BobHanlon +1 very very nice:)

Answer (score 9):

```
Manipulate[{"Area =" <> ToString[N@n Cos[Pi/(2 n)] Sin[Pi/(2 n)]], 
  Graphics[{Circle[], {Yellow, Polygon[CirclePoints[n]]}}]}, {n, 3, 
  50, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I was looking for-something simple!

Comment: I can't figure out how this formula works. Are you scaling the polygon to have a certain radius, or something? As n increases, this seems to approach Pi/2.

Comment: `RegularPolygon[n]` works in place of `Polygon[CirclePoints[n]]` too.

Comment: Manipulate[Column[{StringForm["Area = ``",N[RegionMeasure[RegularPolygon[n]]]],Graphics[{Circle[],{Pink,RegularPolygon[n]}}]}],{n,3,50,1}]

Answer (score 8):

I understand the down voting for this question. However, for fun:

```
p[n_] := {Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ Range[0, n]
piapp[n_] := With[{pg = Polygon[p[n]]},
  Graphics[{Circle[], Red, pg, 
    Text[Style[N@n Sin[2 Pi/n]/2, White, 16], {0, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300]]
anim = Table[
   Row[{
     piapp[num],
     ListPlot[Table[{j, N@j Sin[2 Pi/j]/2}, {j, Range[3, 100]}], 
      GridLines -> {None, {Pi}}, Joined -> True, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
        Point[{num, N@num Sin[2 Pi/num]/2}], 
        Text[Style[num, 
          12], {num, N@num Sin[2 Pi/num]/2} - {-5, 0.25}]}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 3.2}, ImageSize -> 300]}], {num, 
    Range[3, 100]}];
```

The `Table` command can be changed to `Manipulate`. It was used to make animated gif.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate the response despite the down voting!